# Flutter drawer layout not working properly on flutter version = v0.2.3

Tags: dart, flutter

When I click on the drawer layout menu that time drawer doesn't perform any action. Below code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return new MaterialApp(
  title : 'msc',
  home : new Scaffold(
    appBar : new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Msc')
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(accountName: new Text('Msc'), 
accountEmail: new Text('india@msc.com'))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
);
}
}
```

Comment: There's no "hamburger menu" on the code you provided.

Comment: I meant navigation drawer

Comment: @RémiRousselet from the flutter docs, `If the leading widget is omitted, but the AppBar is in a Scaffold with a Drawer, then a button will be inserted to open the drawer.` But @Bijoy, when I run that it works fine - when I tap the menu it opens the drawer. Which version of flutter are you using; it might be worth upgrading to the most recent version.

Comment: Also, does swiping from the left of your screen open the drawer?

Comment: No, that's the issue when I click, the drawer doesn't swipe from left to right. But it was working before. after upgrading my flutter to the newest ver that drawer action is not working.

Comment: just tested it , it works fine for me flutter `v = v0.2.3`

Comment: mine version is `= v0.2.7`

Comment: Now what should I do?

Comment: I just copy paste your code and it is working properly. mine version is = v0.2.8

Comment: Yeah in mine system too. after reinstalling flutter plugin and dart plugin.